# Share collections between tasks within c# application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, task

I have a wpf application in which I have to fill some Collection :

```
 private async Task  FillList()
        {

             await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                           {
                gdpList = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<gdp_groupe>>().GetAll().ToList();
                MedecinGDP.AddRange(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<vue_medecin>>().GetAll());
                CodeGDP_Collection.AddRange(gdpList);
                FiltredParticipant.AddRange(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<fsign_fiche>>().GetAll());
            });
        }
```

The problem is that the collections still empty after I call this method. when I change the method like this (synchrounous way):

```
private void  FillList()
            { 
                    gdpList = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<gdp_groupe>>().GetAll().ToList();
                    MedecinGDP.AddRange(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<vue_medecin>>().GetAll());
                    CodeGDP_Collection.AddRange(gdpList);
                    FiltredParticipant.AddRange(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<fsign_fiche>>().GetAll());

            }
```

the collections become filled!! So I need to know :

How can I share collections between different tasks?

Comment: You probably need some thread synchronization mechanism to coordinate access to the collection.  Google "C# Lock"

Comment: Btw your `FillList` method is never going to complete because you never started the `Task`. Don't use `Task` class constructor; just use `Task.Run` or `Factory.StartNew`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of locking, I would advise to use a collection that is thread-safe. Now, when at the same time the `Add` method is called by multiple threads / tasks, the collection can become invalid. For me, it is easier to use thread-safe collections than `lock` for example. Also, `lock` is quite hard to use when your collection is used by multiple classes.

As [Dave Black](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251267/dave-black) pointed out in a comment, the thread-safe collections use lock-free synchronization which is must faster than taking a lock, as you can read on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).

One of the collections you can use is [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can be compared to `List<T>`.

Comment: I think you can improve this answer if you explain *why* it's better than locking.

Comment: I believe the thread-safe collections use lock-free synchronization which is must faster than taking a lock.

Comment: So that would be another reason not to use lock. Thanks @Dave

Comment: I was correct - refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx