# Make custom C# collection thread-safe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I create this specific collection class :

```
  public class RangeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        private bool _suppressNotification = false;

        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_suppressNotification)
                    base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
            }
            catch  
            {

            }


        }

        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            if (list == null) { 
            return ;
                              }

            _suppressNotification = true;

            foreach (T item in list)
            {

                    Add(item);

            }
            _suppressNotification = false;
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        public void EditElement(int index, object value)
        {
            _suppressNotification = true;
            if (index >= 0 && index < this.Count) this[index] = (T)value;
            _suppressNotification = false;
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
        public void RemoveElementAt(int index)
        {
            _suppressNotification = true;
            if (index >= 0 && index < this.Count) this.RemoveAt(index);
            _suppressNotification = false;
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
        public void RemoveElement(T element)
        {
            _suppressNotification = true;
            this.Remove(element);
            _suppressNotification = false;
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

    }
```

then I'd like to use it like this :

```
         public RangeObservableCollection<vue_medecin > MedecinGDP { get; set; }

        public RangeObservableCollection<gdp_groupe > CodeGDP_Collection { get; set; }

        public RangeObservableCollection<fsign_fiche > FiltredParticipant { get; set; }
    private async Task  FillList()
            {

                 await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                               {
                    gdpList = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<gdp_groupe>>().GetAll().ToList();
                    MedecinGDP.AddRange(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<vue_medecin>>().GetAll());
                    CodeGDP_Collection.AddRange(gdpList);
                    FiltredParticipant.AddRange(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<fsign_fiche>>().GetAll());
                });
            }
```

I'd like to custom `RangeObservableCollection` to make it thread-safe because in my case,concurrent access between principal thread and task can cause problem.

**I'd like to avoid using a concurrent collection (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413870/share-collections-between-tasks-within-c-sharp-application)) because I have to use this collection type in my program.**

So,how can I edit this implementation to accomplish this task?What is the best idea?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say "Thread Safe" what exactly are you wanting to achieve? Do you want concurrent modifications of collection? Do you want to be able to use a IEnumerable while another thread writes to the collection? Depending on what you want to happen will affect what you need to do.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I mean I  want to be able to use a IEnumerable while another thread writes to it

Comment: Why should this collection need to be concerned with this?  It's likely that you'd be better off simply requiring users of this type to synchronize their access to it instead of having this collection try to manage it.

Comment: @Servy In the case of using multiple tasks it is difficult to manage it ( take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413870/share-collections-between-tasks-within-c-sharp-application) .

Comment: @LamloumiAfif Rather than having tasks add values to a collection, have the tasks return the values they compute as a result.  That result can then be accessed by other tasks/operations without needing to worry about synchronization issues.

Comment: @Servy Can you explain your idea plz  with code ( as an answer)

Comment: No, as it is both not even close to an answer to the question as asked, and would require a lot of information about your specific situation which is not at all known.

Comment: @Servy you're right :) look to my edit plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only have a single thread modifying the collection and just want to make sure the readers can access it safely.

If so, you can have your background thread compute new elements, but dispatch adding the elements to your reader thread.  This effectively makes mutating/reading all take place on the same thread, avoiding the issue of synchronization.  I believe this is what Servy was suggesting in the comments.

This is easiest if you're reading from the UI thread, as you can use the standard dispatching mechanisms.  Async/await makes this particularly easy (assuming FillList is called from the UI thread):

```
private async Task  FillList()
{
      gdpList = await Task.Run(() => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<gdp_groupe>>().GetAll().ToList());
      MedecinGDP.AddRange(await Task.Run(() => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<vue_medecin>>().GetAll()));
      CodeGDP_Collection.AddRange(gdpList);
      FiltredParticipant.AddRange(await Task.Run(() => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<fsign_fiche>>().GetAll()));
}
```

Comment: You could make the function a little more parallel if you kicked off the 3 tasks at the start of FillList and kept the tasks returned as variables then awaited the tasks after all 3 have been started.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use

```
private readonly object m_lock = new object();
```

And every time you are accessing your method do the following:

```
lock(m_lock){
     // your code goes here
}
```

Using this will ensure that only one thread at a time can access this piece of code. Hope this helps

Comment: Note that this only makes each method atomic; this can still be problematic if multiple methods are called with any sort of assumption about the state of the collection.

Comment: lock is quite hard to use when your collection is used by multiple classes.

Comment: @LamloumiAfif Indeed; it's why you should do everything you can to avoid having shared state between multiple threads as much as possible, and to limit the scope of that state to be as small as possible when you're forced to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make this custom collection thread-safe because it inherits from a class that is not thread safe.  You may be able to make some of the methods thread-safe (the ones you can override or the ones you write yourself) but not all of them (not all of the members of the base class are virtual).

If you wish to make a custom collection that is thread safe, you should inherit from one of the classes in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.

Another option is to use a container approach instead of inheritance, e.g. write a thread-safe wrapper instead of a descendent class.